# How (and why) upgrade a GitHub workflow to use “Environment files”

Tags: github, gitpython

I have a GitHub action workflow file that is running fine, but recently warnings about ‘set-env’ and ‘add-path’ deprecation have been brought to my attention.  The fix suggested by GitHub is to use “Environment Files”; I.e. pipe values into a file managed by a GITHUB_ENV file descriptor.

My question is : Is GitHub asking me to replace the “env” block of my workflow with a step containing commands of the form ‘echo “{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_ENV’?

I have to also ask why this is necessary, since I think it is lame, but that is really beside the point.

Comment: FYI, there is a possibility that the warning stems from a third party Python package I import from gitpython  The exact source of the use of set-env and add-path in my workflow is unclear, and GitHub’s warning refers simply to line 1 of the directory .github

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience using python with GitHub actions, this is an issue with actions/setup-python versions 1.1.1 and earlier.  You probably have a line in your workflow that reads:

```
uses: actions/setup-python@v1.1.1
```

If you upgrade to version 2 of setup-python, there will be no warning.  Just change the line above to the following:

```
uses: actions/setup-python@v2
```

In order to demonstrate, the log of my [v1.1.1 workflow](https://github.com/nowinnovation/DebugGithubActions/actions/runs/304892859) shows the warnings you mentioned, but the warnings are resolved by using [version 2](https://github.com/nowinnovation/DebugGithubActions/actions/runs/304892862)

Answer (score 3):

> I have to also ask why this is necessary

This was [announced in early Oct. 2020 this month](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/), and pointed to a [moderate security vulnerability](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/security/advisories/GHSA-mfwh-5m23-j46w)

> The `@actions/core` npm module `addPath` and `exportVariable` functions communicate with the Actions Runner over stdout by generating a string in a specific format.
> Workflows that log untrusted data to stdout may invoke these commands, resulting in the path or environment variables being modified without the intention of the workflow or action author.

> For now, users should upgrade to @actions/core v1.2.6 or later, and replace any instance of the set-env or add-path commands in their workflows with the new [Environment File Syntax](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/docs/commands.md#environment-files).
> Workflows and actions using the old commands or older versions of the toolkit will start to warn, then error out during workflow execution.

So:

```sh
echo "FOO=BAR" >> $GITHUB_ENV
echo "/Users/test/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH
```

That is why a GitHub Action like [actions/setup-python](https://github.com/actions/setup-python) has a recent [PR 138](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/pull/138) in order to uses [Environment files](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/docs/commands.md#environment-files) to communicate with the Runner.

But if you are using any other workflow based on `actions/core`, you need to upgrade said `actions/core` version as soon as possible.

Comment: The take-away from [the blog post you refer to](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/)  is _"Action authors who are using the toolkit... "_.  The original action's author might find the message from the toolkit useful, but as the end-user  invoking their action, I was uncertain what the Runner meant by simply repeating it to me. I wish the Runner's error message was more like yours: "dependencies in by this workflow are based on an insecure version of actions/core; check for an updated version of the dependency as soon as possible."